# Can i get the text of a selected option and store it in a variable instead of the select option value

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to get my select option text not the value and store it in a variable, how can i do that, because it's only getting the select option value.

My code below:

This is the select option i want to retrive it text from, not the value

```
               <form method="post" action="/lesson">
                  @csrf
                  <select class="form-control" name="lesson_time">
                       <option disabled>Lesson Time</option>
                      <option value="time1">08:20 AM to 2:30 AM</option>
                      <option value="time2">02:30 AM to 1:00 PM</option>
                      <option value="time3">1:00 PM to 1:50 PM</option>
                      <option value="time4">4:30 PM to 7:10 PM</option>
                    </select>
                   <input type="button" value="Proceed"/>
              </form>
```

After submitting the form above ,how can i get the text property not the value property and store it in a variable

Example

```
$lesson_time = request('lesson_time');
```

Supposing i select option 1 it will store time1 as the value but i want it to store 08:20 AM to 2:30 AM not time1

Comment: You cannot unless you either send it or have a session variable that has a key/value pair that you can use as lookup. Alternative is AJAX

Comment: you can use the same label in value property as well

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Am already using the value property to achieve something else using javascript that is why i did not nullify the value property or use the label property as the value

Comment: you can set an array const, `const lesson_time = ['time1' => '08:20 AM to 2:30 AM', 'time2' => '02:30 AM to 1:00 PM'];` and call it when a particular value is recieved in request

Answer (score 0):

Try putting lesson time in `value=""`.

```
               <form method="post" action="/lesson">
                  @csrf
                  <select class="form-control" name="lesson_time">
                       <option disabled>Lesson Time</option>
                      <option value="08:20 AM to 2:30 AM">08:20 AM to 2:30 AM</option>
                    </select>
                   <input type="button" value="Proceed"/>
              </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, am using the value property in a javascript function, that is why it is not null

Comment: It is never necessary or beneficial to repeat the option tag's text as its `value` attribute -- just omit the declaration.